# Mysql trigger, select and then update

Tags: mysql, triggers

if I create these 2 MySQL triggers separately, both execute ok. But I don't manage to combine them to be able to multiply duration x rate.

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `deduct_balance`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `deduct_balance`
AFTER UPDATE ON `transactions`
FOR EACH ROW
SET @Rate = (SELECT rate FROM languages WHERE languages.idlanguages = contracts.languages_idlanguajes);

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `deduct_balance`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `deduct_balance`
AFTER UPDATE ON `transactions`
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE contracts SET `balance` = balance -(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NEW.end_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(OLD.start_date)) / 60
WHERE contracts.idcontracts = new.contracts_idcontracts

COMBINED (I GET ERROR)
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `deduct_balance`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `deduct_balance`
AFTER UPDATE ON `transactions`
FOR EACH ROW
SET @Rate = (SELECT rate FROM languages WHERE languages.idlanguages = contracts.languages_idlanguajes);
UPDATE contracts SET `balance` = balance -(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NEW.end_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(OLD.start_date)) / 60;
WHERE contracts.idcontracts = new.contracts_idcontracts

Any idea?

I get this error
Error
consulta SQL:

UPDATE contracts SET `balance` = balance -(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NEW.end_date) -   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(OLD.start_date)) / 60;
MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

## 1054 - Unknown column 'NEW.end_date' in 'field list'

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You have an extra ; before WHERE in the COMBINED query. `balance -(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NEW.end_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(OLD.start_date)) / 60; WHERE `

Comment: Right the ; shouldn't be there, but the error continues anyway

Answer (score 0):

It worked this way:
UPDATE contracts 
SET `balance` = balance -(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NEW.end_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(OLD.start_date)) / 60) * (SELECT rate FROM languages WHERE languages.idlanguages = new.languages_idlanguages))
WHERE contracts.idcontracts = new.contracts_idcontracts